# What is the correct way to use "android", "UIApplication", "UIStatusBarAnimation" keyword in NativeScript 7?

Tags: typescript, nativescript, nativescript-angular

I'm migrating a typescript/angular based NativeScript 6.8 to 7.1.2. I try do on [following link](https://nativescript.org/blog/nativescript-7-announcement/). It works well on some parts.
However, I could not find/understand the explanation on native code usage for Android and iOS. I would like to modify the existing code that I used for control StatusBar(Hide/Show).
[image: This is the code for Android]
[image: This is the code for iOS]
How could I fix this code?
To show full original code without errors, I created new project from code on NativeScript6.8 on [this link](https://github.com/NineWoranop/nativescript-statusbar-example).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to update your references.d.ts file for NS7
First install this package `npm i @nativescript/types --save-dev`
Then update your references.d.ts to look like this

```
/// <reference path="./node_modules/@nativescript/types/index.d.ts" />
```